# jdbc odbc for update an existing data?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

What would be the problem with jdbc odbc for update an existing data?

in database i declear "ID" and "FirstName" are text type and "Mobile" is number type(integer).

> Error code : java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

```
private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
             int number;
             String id,fName;
                   id=jTextField1.getText();
                     fName=jTextField2.getText();
                     number=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());

        s.executeUpdate("UPDATE Student set ID='"+id+"','FirstName'"+fName+"',Mobile"+number+" where ID='"+id+"'");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record has been updated");
                System.out.println("Updated");
        DBclose();
        DBopen();
    }

    catch(HeadlessException | SQLException ae){
            System.out.println(ae);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `=` in the query:

```
UPDATE Student set ID='"+id+"','FirstName'"+fName+"',Mobile"+number+" where ID='"+id+"'"
                                    here--^      and here--^
```

You also have a quote that shouldn't be there

```
UPDATE Student set ID='"+id+"','FirstName
                         here--^
```

Hint: if you simply printed the final query, or use a debugger to inspect its value, you would have noticed that immediately.

And you should also learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), to make your code robust (what if the name is O'Reilly for example), and not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Finally, you shouldn't use the JDBC/ODBC driver, which is completely obsolete. Download the database driver for your database and use it.

Comment: Don't blame your teacher. He can't teach you everything. A programmer has to learn new things everyday, by himself.